# Why am I getting transaction out of gas error in remix ide for all my smart contract function?

Tags: remix, blockchain, out-of-gas

This is my Smart Contract Code. I have tried increasing the gas limit in remix but to no avail the same error comes again

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./Contract_2.sol";
import "./Signin.sol";


contract LivingDonor {

    struct LivingTransplantDetails{
        uint256 donor_id;
        uint256 reciever_id;
        string organ;
        int stage;
    }

    struct LivingTimeLine {
        uint256 start_donor_sur;
        uint256 end_donor_sur;
        uint256 start_receiver_sur;
        uint256 end_receiver_sur;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => LivingTransplantDetails) living_trans_Detail;
    
    mapping(uint256 => uint256[4]) living_trans_timeline;
    
    mapping(address => uint256[]) Living;

    uint256 randNonce = 0;

    mapping(uint256 => bool) isRandom;

    function LivingTransDetails(
        uint256 donor_id,
        uint256 reciever_id,
        string memory organ,
        address ContractA_Address
    ) public returns(uint256){
        register ContractA = register(ContractA_Address);
 
        require(
            ContractA.check(msg.sender) == true,
            "No such MetaMask Address..Please Check..!!"
        );

        require(
            ContractA.checkDonor(donor_id) == true,
            "Please check and verify your Donor Id!!"
        );

        require(
            ContractA.checkReciever(reciever_id) == true,
            "Please check and verify your Reciever Id!!"
        );

        uint256 id = 0;

        do {
            id = (++randNonce + block.timestamp) % 1000000;
        } while (isRandom[id] == true);
  
        LivingTransplantDetails memory living_transplant = LivingTransplantDetails(
            donor_id,
            reciever_id,
            organ,
            1
        );

        Living[msg.sender].push(id);

        living_trans_Detail[id] = living_transplant;

        return id;
    }

    function getLivingId() public view returns (uint256){
        return Living[msg.sender][Living[msg.sender].length - 1];
    }

    function getlivingtransdetails(uint256 trans_id) public view  returns(LivingTransplantDetails memory)
    {
            return living_trans_Detail[trans_id];
    }

    
    function getlivingtranstimeline(uint256 trans_id) public view  returns(uint256[4] memory) 
    {
            return living_trans_timeline[trans_id];
    }
    
    
    function start_living_donor_surgery(uint256 transplant_id) public {

        living_trans_timeline[transplant_id][0] = block.timestamp;
        living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage = 2;
    }

    
    function end_living_donor__surgery(uint256 transplant_id
    ) public {
        require(
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage == 2,
            "Sorry complete the previous step first"
        );
        living_trans_timeline[transplant_id][1] = block.timestamp;
        living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage = 3;
    }
    
    function start_living_receiver_surgery(uint256 transplant_id) public {

        require(
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage == 3,
            "Sorry complete the previous step first"
        );
        living_trans_timeline[transplant_id][2] = block.timestamp;
        living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage = 4;
    }


    function end_living_receiver_surgery(
        uint256 transplant_id,
        address ContractA_Address
    ) public {
        
        register ContractA = register(ContractA_Address);

        require(
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage == 4,
            "Sorry complete the previous step first"
        );
        living_trans_timeline[transplant_id][3] = block.timestamp;
        living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].stage = 5;
        ContractA.remove_organ(
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].donor_id,
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].reciever_id,
            living_trans_Detail[transplant_id].organ
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same error.
maybe its bug IDE?
on desktop ide its "ok"

Comment: Make sure you're fulfilling the conditions mentioned in `require()` for the corresponding functions that you're trying to call.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey it worked don't know why the browser version one gives this error

Comment: The code you posted is missing some contract so it is impossible to test. What network are you using to deploy? Do a simple hello world contract also fail? Can you share the exact error message? It could be that the network doesn't support newer opcodes, it could be that it isn't configured, it could be a browser error, etc.